# Google Script - Alert to show which rows have been marked red background

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this code to find blank cells and color their background red. After this I would like an alert to show telling which rows have been marked red.

```
  var blankRows = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
  if(data[i]=="Time: Midwest- Daily Entry"){
  if(data[i+1]==""){ // data contains all the cells in a column
  samsara.getRange(i+2,7).setBackground("red");
  blankRows[i] = i+2; 
  }
  }
}
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert('Extra images detected in rows' + blankRows, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
```

First, I would like the alert to only come up if there are blank rows, I think an if statement would work. Also, the alert shows 'Extra images detected in rows ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,79. Row 79 has a blank cell so this is correct. I assume that the ,,,, are from empty cells in my array blankRows. How can I get the alert to only show actual row numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
 blankRows[i] = i+2;
```

use

```
 blankRows.push(i+2);
```

then replace

```
var response = ui.alert('Extra images detected in rows' + blankRows, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
```

by

```
var response = ui.alert('Extra images detected in rows' + blankRows.join(', '), ui.ButtonSet.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be to create a range for the blank cells and use `getRow()`(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow). Here's what I came up with (You might need to adjust this as my computers old, but you get the idea):

```
var blankRows = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
  if(data[i]=="Time: Midwest- Daily Entry"){
  if(data[i+1]==""){ // data contains all the cells in a column
  samsara.getRange(i+2,7).setBackground("red");
  blankRows[i] = i+2; 
  }
  }
}
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:D10");
var cells = range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
var blank = cells.getRow()
var response = ui.alert('Extra images detected in rows' + blank )
```

info on [SpreadsheetApp.Dimension](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcellsshiftdimension)